# FormatException from SQLDataAdapter.Update caused by null value

Tags: c#, sql-server, xsd, sqldataadapter

My "User" table (SQL Server) has a (int,null) column, ActiveWorkRequestId.
I am trying to update the table using a SqlDataAdapter.  This is set up with a clone of the default Update command based on an XSD strongly typed dataset definition (Visual Studio 2010).  So the command looks like

```sql
UPDATE [User] SET [Username] = @p1, [ActiveWorkRequestId] = @p2
 WHERE (([Id] = @p3) AND ([Username] = @p4) AND ((@p5 = 1 AND
 [ActiveWorkRequestId] IS NULL) OR ([ActiveWorkRequestId] = @p6)))
```

In this example the table "User" has 3 columns: Id, Username and ActiveWorkRequestId.  Parameters p2, p5 and p6 all have an associated column of ActiveWorkRequestId.

The run time parameters for the update command (from the modified row) in this example are:

```
@p1 - "myusername"
@p2 - [DBNull]
@p3 - 126
@p4 - "myusername"
@p5 - [DBNull]
@p6 - [DBNull]
```

I get all the updated rows (there is only one returned), then update as follows.  The ActiveWorkRequestId in the changed row is null (as it was in the original row, in fact).  "dt" is the populated DataTable from my DataSet.

```cs
// This part is inline for convenience, only done once in fact
// Some irrelevant code omitted
string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", dt.TableName);
string sqlCon = ""; // connection string actually got from settings
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlCon);
SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
cb.QuotePrefix = "[";
cb.QuoteSuffix = "]";
da.UpdateCommand = CopyCommandObject(dt, cb.GetUpdateCommand());

// ... This part may execute more than once
DataRow[] foundRows = dt.Select("", "",
    DataViewRowState.Added | DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent);
da.Update(foundRows);   // Exception here

// ... defined elsewhere
private static SqlCommand CopyCommandObject(DataTable dt, SqlCommand cmd)
{
    SqlCommand r = new SqlCommand(cmd.CommandText);
    r.Connection = cmd.Connection;
    foreach (SqlParameter p in cmd.Parameters)
    {
        DataColumn dc = dt.Columns[p.SourceColumn];
        // Put this in since p.IsNullable always seems to be false
        bool nullable = dc.AllowDBNull ? true : false;
        SqlParameter newParam = new SqlParameter(
             p.ParameterName,
             p.SqlDbType,
             p.Size,
             p.Direction,
             nullable,
             p.Precision,
             p.Scale,
             p.SourceColumn,
             p.SourceVersion,
             p.Value);
        r.Parameters.Add(newParam);
    }
    return (r);
}
```

When I call Update on the SqlDataAdapter, a FormatException is thrown:

Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

Inner exception is:

Input string was not in a correct format.

I can't find out which column it is objecting to but the only int column (apart from the PK) is ActiveWorkRequestId.  So it seems that the Update method is treating a null value for a parameter as an empty string and attempting to coerce this to an int32, even if the table column and the parameter are both nullable.

Why can't it just set the column to null (especially as it already is null in the database)?
Can I do anything about this?

I perhaps should mention that the project was just imported into VS2010 (.NET 4.0) from VS2003 (.NET 1.1) where it all worked fine.  This is why the SqlDataAdapter is created in code rather than just using the TableAdapter created by the XSD designer - the .NET 1.1 designer didn't create TableAdapters. (I don't want to have to regenerate all the XSDs if possible).

Comment: Sounds like something may be trying to assign the string "NULL" or "DbNull" as the value of the parameter, instead of the DbNull.Value instance.

Comment: The DataTable row definitely contains DbNull.Value, so if that is incorrectly expanded for the query parameter, then wouldn't that be a bug in ADO.NET?  There is no user code involved in the process.  If this happens for everyone who tries to update a nullable int, date/time etc. with a null using a SqlDataAdapter, then why isn't the Internet full of people complaining about it?

Comment: Looks like this is a long standing issue which Microsoft have no intention of addressing... see e.g. [this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1227689.aspx).  I may try the VS extension mentioned there since it seems to be impossible to use a SqlDataAdapter to update where nullable non-string columns are involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the CopyCommandObject() method, use:

```
da.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand().Clone();
```

This way is simpler, and less error-prone.

Comment: The code was migrated from .NET 1.1 which did not support `SqlCommand.Clone()`, which is presumably why it was done in this longhand way.  However I suspect in the newer Framework not all the required properties were being copied by the old code.